# How can I convert between plain text in JSON in Node-RED function node?

Tags: json, string, function, format, node-red

Node-RED I am trying to send and received emails that humans can read and compose.

Everything else that travels in the flow is in JSON format it seems. So, I have to write code for a function node to convert some text from an email-in to JSON to go to other parts of the flow (I'm sending it out over MQTT).

And I need a function to convert from JSON (coming from MQTT) to some plain text to send out in an email to the human.

I know the function node says you can write code, but I can't find any reference anywhere (searched for 20 minutes) that tells me how to write code for the function node.

I see examples with split() and join() and such, but I don't know how they work and I can't find anything about how that works.

How can I manipulate strings of characters from an email and perform tests on them to create a JSON payload to inject into a flow?  How can I take JSON from a flow and reformat it into plain english for humans?

Comment: The function node takes regular JavaScript. There is some basic documentation here http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions.html

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik
I realized after asking the question that since Node-RED is on Node.js that maybe I could search for a reference for that. Here are a few things I found:
nodejs.org
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/nodejs-for-beginners--net-26314
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: I highly recommend the Mozilla references for all things javascript. Here's the docs on the String object and all the methods available to you to manipulate them - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String .